# how can i find an analytical expression ? findfit ? MATLAB

Tags: curve-fitting

Supposed that i have

```
 fu3 = g.^5.*qQd./(exp(g.^2/T(i)));
    I_value = (1/T^3)*trapz(g,fu3);
```

so, that depends of T and s ( included in qQd ). This calculation take a several minutes. So i want to fit this expression into a easy polynomial expression. I Think the name is fit or interpolation. I want to find a polynomial expression that satisfy my integral of I_value. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your integration range? Let me assume it is pretty large. Then your integrand function varies by many orders of magnitude (did you plot it? probably you need logarithmic scale to understand the full extent of the problem). This is the cause for trapezoidal integration taking minutes. Replacing the integrand by a polynomial is not an option here.

Solution 1: Solve the problem analytically (partial integration, and substitution g^2->u).

Solution 2: If nevertheless you want to do it numerically, use a better integration scheme than equidistant trapezoids. You need an integrator that adapts step width according to magnitude variations of the integrand.